cannot access environmental variable on azure for node js
I have create nodejs server , here i load all the enviromental variables in default.ts file in config folder ,whole server works fine locally but when I host it on azure I need to remove .env file and use environmental variable feature of azure . it hosts well that is index page runs but other routes when accessed by api fails , i doubt it is because of enviromental variable are not accessible as previously it worked fine and this is the only change i made .enter image description here
this is my config file
this is not completely my project so cant try more than i have already said .

Hi, welcome. Just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

Validate all the environment variables and its values in the Azure App Settings and make sure the deployed Node application is loading all environment variables.
As you are using a default.ts file in the config folder, make sure that the config file is reading the environment variables set on Azure.
Check if you are importing the config folder in all the required files properly.
I have added below environment variables in the Azure Web App=>Settings=>Environment Variables:

I have created node application with the below files:
Configured the environment variables in default.ts file in Config folder.
src/config/default.ts:
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

export default {
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  apiUrl: process.env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
};

src/routes/index.ts:
import { Router } from 'express';
import config from '../config/default';
import { getUsers } from '../controllers/usercontroller';

const router = Router();

const apiUrl= config.apiUrl;
const port= config.port;

router.get('/users', getUsers);
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Welcome to the root path! The defined api url "${apiUrl}" running in the port "${port}"`);
  });
export default router;

src/controller/usercontroller.ts:
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import config from '../config/default';

const apiUrl=config.apiUrl;

export const getUsers = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.json({ message: 'List of users and the defined url is: '+apiUrl });
};

src/app.ts:
import express from 'express';
import logger from './middleware/logger';
import router from './routes/index';

const app = express();

app.use(logger);
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', router);
app.use('/', router);

export default app;

Deployed the Node app to Azure:
Able to fetch the environment variables from Web App App Settings:
Portal:
route / (defined in src/index.ts):

route /api/users (defined in src/controller/usercontroller.ts):

